# Filter Collection of Listing depends on Request Parameter

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I'm going to add the request param to filter the Grid Listing.
The url will be like: `abc/xyz/status/2`
And the collection will filter which record that have "`status`" value equal `2`.
I want to found something to add to my listing.xml like:

```
<item name="add_filter" xsi:type="string">status</item>
</item>
```

Comment: Do you need to show this filters in "applied filters" block with possibility of clear filters?

Comment: @Max yes I do. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I have used below code in my module for similar requirement:

```
<dataSource name="listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        ...
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="status" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>    
</dataSource>
```

Here in **`<item name="status" xsi:type="string">*</item>`** **status** is your url request part.

Let me know if need anymore clarification or help.

Answer (score 0):

thats Christian from Germany. I followed your instructiuons to place a url filter in my grid. I have added my grid with "insertlisting" to an ui form fieldset and I tried to get a filter from the url. But nothing works. Can you tell me, what I am doing wrong??

```
    <dataSource name="mcas_ghscategory_ghscategory_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mcas_ghscategory_ghscategory_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">ghscategory_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="ghsclass_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
            </item>
                 <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">ghscategory_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```