# Filtering grid by using filter_url_params is not working

Tags: magento2, collection, grid

I added a grid to a ui_component form and I want to use an Url-parameter to filter the content of the grid. Herefore I added the 'filter_url_params' in my listing:

```
    <dataSource name="mcas_covertemplate_graphicelement_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mcas_covertemplate_graphicelement_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">graphicelement_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="cover_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                </item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">graphicelement_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

The cover_id is visible in my Url, but it is not used to set the filter. 
If I set a value for the `cover_id` manually it works.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: try after cache clear and compile once as code since perfect

Comment: Can you please show your model grid collection file ?

Comment: Can you show your di.xml ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to help the Magento 2 Community I have pushed a simple repository here https://bitbucket.org/shinedev/helpdesk-stackexchange/ it could be cloned and the it could be edited.

*You can install this little sample in your Magento 2.3.x store and click at the Helpdesk button in the menu.*

The Aim is understanding how to nest a listing grid created by the new UIComponent within a UiComponent form.

[image: Ticket UIComponent Form]

At the moment I have succedeed to get the ticket_id by a simple session variable but this is not the main aim and it is not a good workaround too. I would like to understand how Magento 2 developers pass the data from one to another UIComponent.

**Furthermore I have already explained here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/306136/2004 how this thread is really popular at the Magento Community.**

Comment: Have you ever found a way to make this work without the session variable ?