# How to add where condition in resource data model in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, grid

I need to display some records in admin data grid. I am displaying this data grid using xml file. I need to fetch only the records with status = 'Active'. How can I implement this condition in model?

This is my table

[image]

**Collection.php**

```
<?php

 namespace Bridge\Batchcode\Model\ResourceModel\Items;

 class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
 {

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Bridge\Batchcode\Model\Items', 'Bridge\Batchcode\Model\ResourceModel\Items');
    }    
}
```

**bridge_batchcode_items_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
 <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Bridge\Batchcode\Block\Adminhtml\Items" name="adminhtml.block.promo.quote.grid.container">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="adminhtml.block.promo.quote.grid" as="grid">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">bridge_batchcode_items_grid</argument>
                <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Bridge\Batchcode\Model\ResourceModel\Items\Collection</argument>
                <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">sort_order</argument>
                <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Export" name="items.grid.export" as="grid.export">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="exportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">bridge_batchcode/*/export</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="adminhtml.promo.quote.grid.columnSet">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="path" xsi:type="string">bridge_batchcode/*/edit</item>
                        <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="id">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block> 

            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**Bridge/Batchcode/Model/Items.php**

```
<?php

namespace Bridge\Batchcode\Model;

class Items extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

  protected function _construct()
  {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('Bridge\Batchcode\Model\ResourceModel\Items');
  }
}
```

**Bridge\Batchcode\Model\ResourceModel\Items.php**

```
<?php

namespace Bridge\Batchcode\Model\ResourceModel;

class Items extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

  protected function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('batchcode_entity', 'id');
  }
}
```

Is there any method to add condition in select method. I am showing only ID in grid now.

Comment: You want to add query?

Comment: can you update here all file code like model etc.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel model files added

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230570/filtering-grid-by-using-filter-url-params-is-not-working/306441#306441

Comment: still I am not clear, are you making your own extension?

Comment: if yes please share code.

Comment: or share all files here so I try to possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_initSelect()` to filter collection data.

Add the below function in your **Collection.php**

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status', ['eq' => 'active']);
        return $this;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I add this filtering in xml file? collection.php file is a common file, editing this file will affect some other pages

Comment: @GeethuJaison You can create grid collection for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in view in ui_component like as shown below under item name filter_url_params

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="main_table.status" xsi:type="string">1</item>
</item>
```