# Filter admin grid based on the url parameter

Tags: grid, filter, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I have a custom agrid. It has edit option and url parameters.

I need to create another grid in the edit page based on the url parameter. ie., I need to filter the custom grid based on the url parameter.

Note: Am not using ui component to create grid.

Code: https://pastebin.com/z9aww705

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please add your ui component file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Marius answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2/96995#96995)

In the layout xml file, `change the Core Grid block to Custom Grid Block` like below:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="apptha_merchant_post_grid.grid" as="grid">
```

Change this to:

```
<block class="Apptha\Customergroup\Block\Adminhtml\Response" name="apptha_merchant_post_grid.grid" as="grid">
```

Code of the Block File is:

```
<?php
namespace Apptha\Customergroup\Block\Adminhtml;
class Response extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
{    
public function _construct()
{
parent::_construct();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $referenceId = $objectManager->create('Apptha\Customergroup\Model\Deal')
->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->getData("reference_id");
//We'll get the Grid collection here by using this: $this->getCollection()
//We can filter it like addFieldToFilter method
//Here I am filtering grid collection using reference id
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('reference_id', array('eq' => $referenceId));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find below line in your ui component file.

```
<item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
```

After that add below code after that line.

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array"> 
     <item name="id" xsi:type="boolean">1</item>
 </item>
```

You can get filter data in your grid.

Still you have any query let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is not in ui component.

Comment: where you need it ?

Comment: I mean I am not using Ui component to create this grid. I am using normal blocks.

Comment: could you please post your code?

Comment: please find my code here https://pastebin.com/z9aww705

Comment: could you please add your collection code over there.

Comment: I want to apply filter on grid load.

Comment: Great! It's working. In my case, I want to filter another column, not the id. The field I want to filter is seller_id. Please tell me how can I achieve this.